# remove undefined "worksheet" phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am trying to export data from php to excel using PHPExcel,
this is my code :

```
public function testAction(){
    require_once 'PHPExcel.php'; 
    $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(0); //Setting index when creating
    $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Test 1')
                   ->setCellValue('B1', 'Test 2');

    $objWorkSheet->setTitle("Test Sheet");

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    $filename = "test.xlsx"; // month and year should be change
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename . ' ');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
}
```

its work, 
but when i open the file, i found sheet "Worksheet",

[this is the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6bAI.png)

i want to export the file, without the "Worksheet" sheet but i dont know where the sheet come from

Comment: Have you tried if changing worksheet number to 1 fixes it? `$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(1);` ? Or better, don't create worksheet, just use `getActiveSheet` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new PHPExcel object always has a single sheet already, but you're creating a new (econd) sheet to populate as well.... why not simply populate the single worksheet that a new PHPExcel object already gives you.

Change

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
 $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet(0); //Setting index when creating
```

to

```
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: yeah its work, its my first time using PHPExcel, thank you @mark